# Performance of Auto Reset event with Multi-thread application

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, trading

I have developed a Financial Services Application based on Stock Trading. The idea behind application is to perform various calculations of multiple symbols/scrips and generate buy and sell signals for each symbol simultaneously. The data is received per second from data vendor and then calculation is performed.

**Background:**
For this I have created a Calculations Class where it will receive data for a single symbol and perform calculations and generates Buy/Sell Signals.

To Perform calculations for multiple symbols, I am instantiating calculations object in separate thread for each symbol like so

```
    EventWaitHandle ew = new AutoResetEvent(initialState: false);
    Thread t = new Thread(() => RunCalculations(s));
    _waitList.Add(s.Symbol, ew);
    t.Name = s.Symbol;
    t.Start();
    threadList.Add(s.Symbol, t);
```

The above code is iterated through foreach on each symbol. 
This is what happens is `RunCalculations();`

```
    private void RunCalculations(Symbols symbol)
    {
        Calculations calc = new Calculations(symbol);
        while (true)
        {
            _waitList[symbol.Symbol].WaitOne();
            if(!keepRunning[symbol.Symbol])
            {
                calc.Stop();
                return;
            }
            MarketData d = null;
            if(_mktDataQueue.TryDequeue(out d))
            {
                if (calc.SymbolName == d.Symbol)
                    calc.AddTickItem(d);
            }
        }
    }
```

`calc.AddTickItem()` will send only data value of one symbol which belongs to a thread. Further Calculations are called inside `Addtickitem` method of `calc` object.

Through AutoResetEvent, Iam adding a data item in another method which calls `_waitList[data.Symbol].Set();` on each thread.

**Problem**
Calculations are working fine. But the issue is with performance when adding more threads(or symbols). We have tested the limit and found, it can only work properly with around 18 - 20 symbols. If we add more, then calculations part are getting delayed at half hour before end of market hours. But until that time, it works fine. And another catch point is, this does not happen every day. We have tested upto 28 symbols and brought back to 19 where it is working stable now.

As I understand, Since Iam using Event Signalling, it should not be more resource intensive towards CPU. CPU is actually a 2 core intel i3 processor.

But still I would like to know, if its the problem of processor or should I change the architecture of application? I have thought of changing architecture for thread management where instead of symbol, I would take each calculation part in different thread. But the issue is, there are some dependent calculations where the evil concurrent synchronization;) giving me nightmares.

I will change the processor, but I would have to know what could be optimum processor (4 Core, 8 Core, etc..). As I understand only having cores does not solve the problem.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It is very wrong code, it will fail badly if the event is signaled twice.  The more symbols you add, the more likely that gets.  You can't implement a correct producer-consumer with an AutoResetEvent.  Google ".net producer consumer queue" for basic hits.

Comment: I would suggest to change the whole approach and make use of messaging and queues. You can setup different end-points based for scale-ability, redundancy etc. Look at using an ESB like Shuttle: https://github.com/Shuttle

Comment: @HansPassant Yeah... I have thought about that... But I have Separated AutoResetEvents for each thread. So each thread will have its own AutoResetEvent. This should minimize the chance of signalling twice. The data which I receive has a minimum of 1 second and maximum of about 2 min period difference for individual symbol.It is a case of single producer and multiple consumers. But I see your point.... Thanks...

Comment: @NeillVerreynne, But In my case I cannot be building up queues and hope for calculating data points at a later stage. The reaction time should minimum as much as possible. It does not help even If 2 or 3 data points are waiting in queue for calculation at later stage, rather I can skip those data point and take next one. I can skip, but not too much...

Comment: Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's impossible to evaluate what if anything could be causing a performance problem. It may or may not be related to the use of `AutoResetEvent`. That said, `ARE` uses native Windows events which are not as efficient in this context as the `Monitor` class, or even possible one of the other .NET synchronization objects. So you might try switching to one of those.